# Twitter Bootstrap form submit modal

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and i am looking to have a form that when i submit it the modal will appear asking me "Are you sure you want to delete Person" Is there any way to make the button there a submit for the form that had just been filled out?

In other examples I have used used a link for the button which would be a link to site.com/do_delete_person/person_id_18 which is the modalUrl in the JS file

```
<a href="' + modalUrl + '" class="btn btn-primary showhouse-colour">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes
</a>
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No
</button>
```

but for this i need the modal to submit the preceeding form

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution..I used window.location to redirect them to delete url upon confirm

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" class="delete-item btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-id="25">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="delete-url"/>
           Are you sure you want to delete this item?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary confirm">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.delete-item').click(function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
        var delete_url = 'http://yourdomain.com/delete/'+id;
        jQuery('#delete-url').val(delete_url);
         jQuery("#myModal").modal('show');    
    });
    jQuery('.confirm').click(function(){
        window.location = jQuery('#delete-url').val();
    });
});
```